# NetSuite - saved search- dynamic date range formula

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

Is it possible to write dynamic date range formula in NetSuite Saved Search? For example I have one of the expression in results tab is | case when {type} = 'Sales Order' and {custbody6} = 'F' then {amount} else 0 end  |  and I want to be able to add the dynamic date range to this like, and when {date} or {datecreated} is within 'last week' or 'last month' etc....

Answer (score 2):

There are many search date filters, such as `thisWeek`, `lastWeek`, etc. You can find them listed in NS help, under `Search Date Filters`. The filters are supported in formulas also.

Comment: What I need is guidance on how would I re-write my above existing (expression) with one of the dynamic date range filters that are available in NetSuite...such as 'last week'?

Comment: In the UI, select `Formula (Date)` and you'll see the available filters.

Comment: If I set the date on entire search, then other data on this saved search will also be effected. I have other formula lines on this saved search on which I don't want date filter to apply, therefore this needs to be written as part of case statement.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to do something like; `case when {today} - {datecreated} <= 90 then 1 else 0 end`. 90 being the days.